# change background color of a grid based on RadioButton

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding

i have a grid with a gray color, containing 3 radiobutton 'Yes/No/Pending', now, i want to change the color of the grid based on the seleceted value.

if the value is yes, the grid will become Green.

if the valie is No, the grid will become Red, and so on.

and i want all that to happen in xaml only no code behind,
here is my the code :

```
<Grid Background="#FFF2F2F2" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="grid19" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151">
                        <RadioButton Content="Yes" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,12,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        <RadioButton Content="No" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,12,0,0" Name="radioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        <RadioButton Content="Pending" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,12,0,0" Name="radioButton3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </Grid>
```

many thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Grid Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="grid19" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="151">
        <RadioButton Content="Yes" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,12,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <RadioButton Content="No" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,12,0,0" Name="radioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <RadioButton Content="Pending" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,12,0,0" Name="radioButton3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF2F2F2" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=radioButton1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=radioButton2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=radioButton3, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
```

Note that I have removed the default Background and added it as a setter, because adding it directly will override every other Background Property. Hope this will help you.